# Marvin Plugin Attributes

Tags: java, attributes, marvin-framework, marvinproject

I recently found Marvin and have been messing around with it a bit. The main bottleneck I've come across, though, is that there isn't much documentation provided with it. The Javadocs page is sparse and there are very few useful examples provided on the website.

Most of it can be pieced together and worked out, but I really wish there was a detailed list for each of the Image Plugins that are included.
I was wondering, is there's anyone that's used Marvin enough to come up with this list, or just the most common and useful attributes?

This would make using Marvin such a breeze. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're working to improve [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/) documentation and developer resources as most as we can.

**1. MarvinPluginCollection**

The easiest way to play with plug-ins is using **MarvinPluginCollection**. Use static import to have access to all plug-ins as methods:

```
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;
```

The [Javadoc](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/javadoc/marvin/MarvinPluginCollection.html) describe each plug-in and its attributes.

**2. Examples**

We've been adding new examples. Take a look at the [Examples](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples.html) page. You can download [MarvinSamples](https://sourceforge.net/projects/marvinproject/files/Marvin%20Samples/MarvinSamples_1.4.0.zip/download) project which has additional examples. You can also take a look at Stack Overflow questions related to Marvin:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marvin-framework

**3. How-to do in Image Processing**

We're creating a [How-To](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/howto.html) of basic image processing operations. Take a look!

**4. Discussion Group**

If you have any question you can also ask it on [Marvin Discussion Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/marvin-project) specifically to developers using Marvin.

We're sorry for your frustration. We take this post as an incentive to keep improving the framework and developer resources.